# Creating multiple google charts recursively

Tags: javascript, php, charts, google-visualization

We are currently trying to include multiple google charts one a single web page. Below is the php file that we are using to create the google charts.
We have a for loop in our main function that will call graph_data($ratingsss) to create the google charts. When we run the load the page and run the query only one chart gets printed out.

```
    Funtion main()
    for ($ranking->rewind(); $ranking->valid(); $ranking->next()) {
        $ratingsss = $ranking->current()->get_rating();
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td class="Times New Roman"><font size="2" color="white"> ' . $counter . '. ' . $ranking->current()->get_name() . ' School rating    for demographic profile: ' . $ranking->current()->get_rating() . '</font></td>';
        echo graph_data($ratingsss);
        $counter++;
     }

     function graph_data($ratingsss) {
         echo'<td> 
         <script type="text/javascript">
         google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
         google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
         function drawChart() {
             var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
             ["Element", "Density", { role: "style" } ],
             ["Silver", ' . $ratingsss . ', "#b87333"],
             ["Silver", 10.49, "silver"],
             ["Silver", 19.30, "gold"],
             ["Platinum", 21.45, "color: #e5e4e2"]
         ]);

         var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
         view.setColumns([0, 1,
                         { calc: "stringify",
                           sourceColumn: 1,
                           type: "string",
                           role: "annotation" },
                         2]);

         var options = {
             title: "Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3",
             width: 600,
             height: 400,
             bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
             legend: { position: "none" },
         };
         var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
         chart.draw(view, options);
      }
      </script>
 <div id="columnchart_values" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div>
 <div id="columnchart_values" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div>
 <div id="columnchart_values" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div>';

      echo'</td>';
      echo'</tr>';  }
```

Comment: I don't see how this is recursive. None-the-less what is the value of your $counter at the end of the looop?

Comment: Its not recursive. We need to make google charts recursively and are confused how to go about it. We are just showing what we have so far.

Answer (score 0):

It's not suprising that you are only able to generate 1 chart.

```
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
```

The line above needs to be updated. It seems you may be adding each chart to the same element each time. And on top of that you have multiple elements with the same id. That will absolutely not work.

Try changing that, it may work.. but it's not pretty. You also seem to have a couple typo's in your code. (at least I hope it's typos ;) )

---

However you are taking the wrong approach to solving this problem. I really doubt google intended that you load the same scripts ( because they are the same scripts ) more than once.

Why don't you just load the script once normally then prep the table with empty rows and then fill them dynamically ( with js )?

*Here is an untested example (supposing you're using jquery, if not let me know and I'll do the js version):*

```
    Funtion main()
        for ($ranking->rewind(); $ranking->valid(); $ranking->next()) {
            $ratingsss = $ranking->current()->get_rating();
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td class="Times New Roman"><font size="2" color="white"> ' . $counter . '. ' . $ranking->current()->get_name() . ' School rating    for demographic profile: ' . $ranking->current()->get_rating() . '</font></td>';
            echo '<td class="gchart" data-rating="'.$ratingsss.'"><div style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div></td>';
            $counter++;
         }
}
```

Then load your js once (name it whatever you want. main.js, googleChartHandler.js etc):

```
$('.gchart').each(function(index, value){
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
             google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
             function drawChart() {
                 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                 ["Element", "Density", { role: "style" } ],
                 ["Silver", $(this).data('rating') , "#b87333"],
                 ["Silver", 10.49, "silver"],
                 ["Silver", 19.30, "gold"],
                 ["Platinum", 21.45, "color: #e5e4e2"]
             ]);

             var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
             view.setColumns([0, 1,
                             { calc: "stringify",
                               sourceColumn: 1,
                               type: "string",
                               role: "annotation" },
                             2]);

             var options = {
                 title: "Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3",
                 width: 600,
                 height: 400,
                 bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
                 legend: { position: "none" },
             };
             var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart($(this).find('div'));
             chart.draw(view, options);
});
```

Good luck. Hope this helped.